# Automatic generate a sales order line for every sales order

Tags: dynamics-nav, ecommerce-sales

Im experimenting with Dynamics Nav 2009.
Is there a way to automatically insert a sales line every time I make a new sales order?
I want postage to be included everytime Im making a new sales order.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve this, one without programming, and one almost without programming.

If you postage line is a standard "charge" added to all orders then you can actually use the "Invoice Discount" functionality. Besides allowing you to assign an actual discount (typically being applied if the order is above a specific amount), then you can also use the functionality to add a "Service Charge". Either to be inserted on all orders, or only if the order total is below a certain "Minimum Amount".

You set it up by specifying the "Invoice Discount Code" field on the Customers and enable the automatic calculation in the "Calc. Inv. Disc." field in "Sales & Receivable Setup" table. The postage lines are not inserted as actual sales lines, but are calculated and applied when posting (or using the total / statistics button).

The other option is the use the "Standard Sales Codes". Here you can specify a number standard lines which are to be inserted whenever the standard sales code are selected. This is where I said a little programming is required, as the system doesn't automatically insert the lines. But you can insert a call to the function to insert the lines automatically when the customer no. has been entered.

Answer (score 1):

This change would most likely require a modification from your NAV Partner.

The modification could add C/AL code to automatically insert a new Sales Line every time a new Sales Header record is created.

```
OnInsert()

SalesLine.INIT;
SalesLine."Document Type" := "Document Type";
SalesLine."Document No." := "No.";
SalesLine."Line No." := 0;
// Additional Code
SalesLine.INSERT(TRUE);
```